# Help my friend leave his invisible clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

My friend (profile name *kai*) joined an open level 6 clan. But while trying to leave the clan, the clan details don't show up and go blank.

Can somebody suggest ways to get rid of the clan?

Comment: If everybody leaves the clan, the clan will be invisible to everyone. (Unless you have it bookmarked)

Comment: When I tap my clan icon, it keeps loading..Interestingly, the clan has 51 members out of 50

Comment: seems like a bug

Answer (score 2):

Send a bug report to the dev by going to settings, then you can type a report in.
If you can contact the leader of the clan, tell him or her to abolish the clan.